# Can we run one it block from one file and one it block from 2nd file and we have 100s of it block in both files in jasmine protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Like in **JUnit** we have **category** annotation where we define **regression, sanity name** and set this category in **pom.xml** file to run only those Testcases. We dont need to change anything afterwards.

can we do same in Jasmine Protractor???

If we do have one file which is **firstfile.ts**

```
describe('angular-material paginator component page', () => {
  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  beforeAll(async() => {
    await browser.get('https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples');
  });

  it('Should navigate to next page', async() => {
    await $('button[aria-label=\'Next page\']').click();
     });

  it('Should navigate to previous page', async() => {
    await $('button[aria-label=\'Previous page\']').click();
 });

  it('Should change list length to 5 items per page', async() => {
    await $('mat-select>div').click();

    });
});
```

like this we have one more spec file and i want to set categories of the it block so i can write that only one word and run the test like in JUnit.

other than the option of f and x before describe and it block.

Comment: No. `fdescribe` and `fit` are your only options unless you come up with some clever solution on your own.

Comment: So, if i have 100s of specs in single spec file then i can not run 20 specs other than the option f and x..??

Answer (score 0):

For annotation based execution you can try BDD in protractor with cucumber.

Here you can create features which can be organised and executed.

Refer this github repo : https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript.git

Please try to clone this repo and understand how it works.